# Flutter lifecycle suspending method not getting called

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using a very simple code to check the working of `suspending` method in the Flutter lifecycle callbacks when I exit the app by pressing back button from the device. But it's not getting called.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  WidgetsBinding binding = WidgetsBinding.instance;

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    print("state: $state");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    binding.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text("Center"));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    binding.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: are you testing on ios or android ?

Comment: I am testing on Android. I know there is no equivalent of `suspending` on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the [didPopRoute()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver/didPopRoute.html) lifecycle hook for back button on Android. From the docs:

> Called when the system tells the app to pop the current route. For example, on Android, this is called when the user presses the back button.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  WidgetsBinding binding = WidgetsBinding.instance;

  @override
  Future<bool> didPopRoute() {
    // Android user pressed back button
    final bool preventAppFromClosing = true;
    return preventAppFromClosing;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    binding.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    binding.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, please write the code, I'll be happy to accept it as answer.